# Running UIAutomation scripts on multiple iOS devices via Instruments command line

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, ios-ui-automation

Are there any way to run UIAutomation scripts in multiple connected iOS devices? Currently I use instruments with -w switch along with UDID of each device?

I appreciate your ideas.

Comment: You mean running them at the same time? Alas, no. Instruments is currently not set up to control two processes at the same time with UI Automation. I'm curious to know what you're trying to do. Are you trying to test two instances of the app talking to each other?

Comment: we are building a tool [Phresco](http://github.com/phresco/phresco) has capability of handling multiple technologies. What we are trying is to run the same automation scripts on multiple devices (iPhone 4, iPhone 5 that are configured one with Wi-Fi and one with 3G network). We can do it one after the other. I just wanted to try as we could run automation tests in multiple devices in multiple devices.

Comment: Yeah, that's not possible at this time.